# Perform insert or update on table using trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, database

I am trying to fetch some values from php page and perform trigger in mysql database. Which is as below:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER /*!50032 IF EXISTS */ `test`.`MysqlTrigger`$$

CREATE
    /*!50017 DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost' */
    TRIGGER `MysqlTrigger` AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON `table2` 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF(NEW .flag=0) THEN
    INSERT INTO temp(sent,pcount,ncount) VALUES (NEW.sent,NEW.pcount,NEW.ncount);
    ELSE
        UPDATE temp SET pcount=NEW.pcount AND ncount=NEW.ncount WHERE id = NEW.id;
    END IF; 
    END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Which gives error:

```
error Code : 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'or update ON `table2` 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    if(NEW .flag=0) then
    INSERT INTO' at line 3
```

I tried to change = with =: but error persist. Any idea whaat the prob?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I count do it. There was problem in syntax. Here is the correct which perform update insert at same moment in different table and update-inset on same table but with if else:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER /*!50032 IF EXISTS */ `test`.`MysqlTrigger2`$$

CREATE
    /*!50017 DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost' */
    TRIGGER `MysqlTrigger2` AFTER INSERT ON `table2` 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF 'flag'=1 THEN
        UPDATE record SET sent=NEW.sent WHERE id=NEW.id;
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO record VALUES (id,NEW.sent);
        INSERT INTO temp VALUES ()
    END IF;
    END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't define a trigger for update **and** insert at the same time. You have to define 2 triggers:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `Mysql_insert_Trigger` AFTER INSERT ON `table2` ...
CREATE TRIGGER `Mysql_update_Trigger` AFTER UPDATE ON `table2` ...
```

Comment: I could do it as update and insert both are with if else so they would not executed at the same moment.